# How to retopologize asymetrical meshes not aligned to a global axis

Tags: topology

I have a high poly mesh that isn't symmetrical. The body is turned one way and the face another. Also, the face itself isn't completely symmetrical. I'd like to be able to use the mirror adjustment when I retopologize as much as possible, but obviously I can't just mirror along a global axis. Is it possible to mirror along a local axis, and if so, how would I appropriately set up that axis to mirror the face?

If it isn't possible to mirror the face properly, how important is it to make the face topology symmetrical? I tried just doing the whole face manually and I suspect I screwed it up. How much does it matter if I have edge loops going off any which way?

[image: Face Retopology]

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Patrick on BlenderArtists.org for helping me find the solution. (https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-retopologize-asymetrical-meshes-not-aligned-to-a-global-axis/1236449/3). The mirror modifier *is* local. My mistake was setting the retopology mesh origin as the center instead of the high poly mesh origin as the center. Also, my topology work above is pretty hamhanded. http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/FaceTopology seems to have some nice color coded examples of how the flow is supposed to look on faces.